# Swift Chart: customize X-axis composed of Date

Tags: swift, swiftui, charts

This question might sound silly, but I spent a lot of time trying without figuring it out.

My data represents a vehicle speed over time, with a granularity around the second. Thus many data.
I want to customize the X-axis (the time) such that it only shows labels for each minute, or better, for each 30 second.

Here is my code so far (showing the graph properly, but the X-axis not working/displaying):

```
Chart {
    ForEach(orderedLocations) { item in
        LineMark(x: .value("Date", "\(item.timestamp!)"),
                 y: .value("Speed", item.groundSpeed),
                 series: .value("Ground Speed", "A"))
        .interpolationMethod(.catmullRom)
        .foregroundStyle(.blue)
        AreaMark(x: .value("Date", "\(item.timestamp!)"),
                 y: .value("Speed", item.groundSpeed),
                 series: .value("Speed", "A"))
    }
}
.chartXAxis {
    AxisMarks(values: .automatic(minimumStride: 60)) { date in
        AxisValueLabel(format: .dateTime.minute())
    }
}
```

What's wrong in this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the x value has to be of type `Date` and has to be not interpolated in a `String`:

```
LineMark(x: .value("Date", item.date),
         y: .value("Speed", item.groundSpeed),
         series: .value("Ground Speed", "A"))
```

So you have to convert your timestamp to a `Date` first.

As `AxisMark` you can stride by minutes to show a label each minute:

```
AxisMarks(values: .stride(by: .minute)) { date in
    AxisValueLabel(format: .dateTime.minute())
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know how I did not notice that I was interpolating. You helped a lot, thanks! Now I'm going to try to have data every two minutes :-).